# Returning html with AJAX and Rails prints out object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using AJAX to return back this HTML:

```
<%= @groups_list.each do |group| %>
<!--One Group Tile-->
<div class="groups-tile">
    <div class="groups-tile-image" style="background:url(img/clubhouse-test.jpg) no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
        <%= group.name %>
    </div>
    <div class="groups-tile-meta">
        <div class="margin-top-10 small-text">
            40 Members
        </div>
        <div class="small-gray-text">
            Next Event: February 15, 2014
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/One Group Tile-->
<% end %>
```

The controller code is such:

```
render 'pagelayouts/orglist', layout: false
```

For some reason when I get the response via AJAX it pastes in the object at the end in text format like this:

```
[#<Org id: 2, created_at: "2014-02-09 20:06:08", updated_at: "2014-02-09 20:06:08", name: "Boys and Girls Club", ppname: nil, ppphone: nil, ppemail: nil, ppskype: nil, approved: nil, username: nil, password: nil, description: nil, timezone: nil, zipcode: 94134>, #<Org id: 3, created_at: "2014-02-09 20:06:53", updated_at: "2014-02-09 20:06:53", name: "Hello Org", ppname: nil, ppphone: nil, ppemail: nil, ppskype: nil, approved: nil, username: nil, password: nil, description: nil, timezone: nil, zipcode: 94118>]
```

Any ideas why this may be? Also, how can I turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the '=' (equal sign) from this line:

```
<%= @groups_list.each do |group| %>
```

It's causing the view to print the array you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was really getting frustrated. I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes when I can.

Comment: Happened to me a couple of times. :P Glad I could help.